# Selecting features from partial string in where clause with variable of Select Layer By Attribute in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute, format

I am new to coding using ArcPy.

My code is:

```
roadname = "Ly Thuong Kiet"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("inLayer_lyr","NEW_SELECTION",""" "DIA_CHI" LIKE '{0}' """.format(roadname))
```

This code can run easily. However, I want to choose all the elements belonging to "DIA_CHI" field that have a name in the roadname.
Example: "Hem 32 Ly Thuong Kiet" will be contained in ("Ly Thuong Kiet").

When I wrote this code:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("inLayer_lyr","NEW_SELECTION",""" "DIA_CHI" LIKE "%Ly Thuong Kiet")
```

It can run. But when I use variable , I couldn't use percentage sign (%) in format.

Comment: Try [escaping it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the most "pythonic" solution, but you could simply avoid the .format by using string concatenation

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("inLayer_lyr","NEW_SELECTION",""" "DIA_CHI" LIKE '%""" + roadname + "'")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I can do it.

Comment: Hi! But could you explain to me why we have to use the percentage sign % like that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing it like this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("inLayer_lyr","NEW_SELECTION","DIA_CHI LIKE '%{0}'".format(roadname))
```

Delimiters around field names have not been needed for quite a few versions and dispensing with them simplifies the syntax.